# Is it possible to send images via FCM?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been receiving HTML5 pushes from different websites and some of them include images.

I couldn't find in the FCM documentation how to send images; is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not the usual use-case for Push Notifications. For FCM, it is strongly advised not to send over images (if ever you manage to), primarily because of the payload size limit - 2KB for `notification`, 4KB for `data`.

I suggest using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) for storing the images, then downloading it in the client when needed, sending the download URL in the push notification as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear; I would like to display an image on the browser notification!

Comment: Hi @runixo My answer still stands. FCM is not advisable for this.

Comment: I'm fine with sending the image URL; as I do with the `icon`. But I don't know how to make the notification popup to display it!